# Does extension slow down app's performance?

Tags: ios, swift

So i have been somewhat thwarted from using extension in my new work place and the reason is that it slows the app down?

Is it true? I cant seem to find any article that verifies this

Cuz i am so used to using extensions to wrap things of similar functionalities, same protocol together.

Answer (score 1):

Extensions do not affect application performance, because in general it's gets compiled into the same machine code, especially when using Whole-Module-Optimization.

However huge number of extensions might affect your app's compile times. Take a look at [this benchmark](https://github.com/DmitryBespalov/swift-extensions-performance).